# SAS Many to Many Merge

Tags: join, merge, sas, many-to-many

Below is the data i have an am trying to merge. I have also included the expected output but my code is only merging on the first match.

I have Data in Beta that is updated the following week. For instance for 9/6 week (it updates on 9/14 per say). This data changes week to week and as it updates Alpha table starts pulling in the next week. Beta only contains a monday date so i have dateparted it to get the week date to match this with every day of that week which is stored in beta. So since 9/6wk is 22592 i want to match with every day of that week stored in alpha so that would be 9/6-9/10. So i have date parted those dates as well so it displays which week they are thus beta should match with dates 9/6-9/10 in this example.

Note i do not expect or what to match with future weeks but i still need to keep the content. So i just want to match the previous week data in Beta with the previous weeks data in Alpha.

Beta table: only houses previous weeks data
alpha table: houses previous week + current week data.

I want to take the data in B

Table Alpha- This table stores the main info including the dates of each week mon-friday. Note this monday was not included due to holiday.

| ID | PKG | Week | IS | SE | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 70 | 17AB | 22529 | Y | N | 9/7/2021 |
| 70 | 17AB | 22529 | Y | N | 9/8/2021 |
| 70 | 17AB | 22529 | Y | N | 9/9/2021 |
| 70 | 17AB | 22529 | Y | N | 9/10/2021 |
| 70 | 17AX | 22536 | - | N | 9/13/2021 |
| 70 | 12AX | 22536 | - | N | 9/14/2021 |
| 70 | 17AX | 22536 | - | N | 9/15/2021 |

Table Beta- this table stores 2 extra columns of data relevant to table alpha. However it contains no dates but the Monday date for the previous week and info relevant to that.

| ID | PKG | Week | add1 | Add2 | Monday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 70 | 17AB | 22529 | Y | N | 9/6/2021 |
| 70 | 17AX | 22529 | Y | N | 9/6/2021 |

Data want

| ID | PKG | Week | IS | SE | add1 | add2 | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 70 | 17AB | 22529 | Y | N | Y | N | 9/7/2021 |
| 70 | 17AB | 22529 | Y | N | Y | N | 9/8/2021 |
| 70 | 17AB | 22529 | Y | N | Y | N | 9/9/2021 |
| 70 | 17AB | 22529 | Y | N | Y | N | 9/10/2021 |
| 70 | 17AX | 22529 | Y | N | Y | N | 9/7/2021 |
| 70 | 17AX | 22529 | Y | N | Y | N | 9/8/2021 |
| 70 | 17AX | 22529 | Y | N | Y | N | 9/9/2021 |
| 70 | 17AX | 22529 | Y | N | Y | N | 9/10/2021 |
| 70 | 17AX | 22536 | - | N |  |  | 9/14/2021 |
| 70 | 12AX | 22536 | - | N |  |  | 9/15/2021 |
| 70 | 17AX | 22536 | - | N |  |  | 9/16/2021 |

My attempt:

```
DATA Alpha; drop monday;
Merge Alpha (in=a) Beta (in=b);
by id pkg week;
if a;
run;
```

i tried this because i need to keep everything in table A but want to add the info in table B. However its only matching on the first one.

Comment: That is not one to many that's many to many....do you need to add date to the merge? Otherwise if you have 2 of the key in one data set and 3 in the other you'll end up with 6. I suspect you need to modify your merge logic somehow.

Comment: Table Alpha houses the only date i need. Beta table only contains monday dates which is why i used a datepart on both tables and put both in week.2 format and am merging on week.

Comment: 'week.2' is not a FORMAT.  Did you mean you use INTNX() to calculate a new date using the 'week.2' interval?

Comment: yes, my apologies! i used format to change the date to format 10 that you see above. But i used week2 in intnx to get the week/datepart

Comment: Why does the second table have 4 duplicate observations?

Comment: Good catch! Looks like i forgot to change those when typing/copying and pasting. My fault on that one. Editing the topic to add more details

Comment: Which column is part of the key you want to use to match is it DATE or WEEK or MONDAY?  Why is WEEK displayed as raw number of days instead using a date type format? Why are some of the values of WEEK not equal to DATE for the same observation? What is the difference between WEEK and DATE?

Comment: How come you have more records in the end table if you're only keeping the ones in TableA? How are they becoming multiples?

Comment: For example, the fifth row in your expected output has date with an ID/PKG/WEEK key that isn't in either input files....

Comment: In your example data the key variables for the merge are only ID and PKG.  If one or more of those date values need to be used in the merge then you need more examples that show how.  If you include WEEK then only the first ID,PKG combination has a match in BETA.

Comment: @Tom Beta only houses last Monday’s date and nothing else. I need to match everything in beta to every day in alpha of that week. So last week is week 22592 and so in alpha that would be dates 9/7-9/10 in this case. So I want the data in beta that matches that that iD Package and week. If I don’t match on week it will start matching on future weeks in alpha table which is not good since the data in Beta will change to match that future week next week

Comment: To confirm yes, beta will only match some of alpha and I need to keep all of alpha which I why I tried the “if a;”

Answer (score 1):

**Your code works fine.**  But since you include the WEEK variable as a key for the merge the second ID/PKG combination from ALPHA will not match any observations from BETA since the week value in ALPHA is one week after the week value in BETA.

With your sample data you only need to use ID and PKG to merge ALPHA and BETA.

```
data alpha; 
  input ID $ PKG $ WeekA :yymmdd. IS $ SE $ DATE :yymmdd.;
  format weekA date yymmdd10.;
cards;
70 17AB 2021-09-06 Y N 2021-09-07
70 17AB 2021-09-06 Y N 2021-09-08
70 17AB 2021-09-06 Y N 2021-09-09
70 17AB 2021-09-06 Y N 2021-09-10
70 17AX 2021-09-13 - N 2021-09-13
70 17AX 2021-09-13 - N 2021-09-14
70 17AX 2021-09-13 - N 2021-09-15
;

data beta;
  input ID $ PKG $ WeekB :yymmdd. Add1 Add2 Monday :yymmdd.;
  format weekB monday yymmdd10.;
cards;
70 17AB 2021-09-06 Y N 2021-09-06
70 17AX 2021-09-06 Y N 2021-09-06
;

data want;
  merge alpha beta;
  by id pkg ;
run;
```

Results:

```
ID PKG       WeekA IS SE       DATE       WeekB Add1 Add2     Monday

70 17AB 2021-09-06 Y  N  2021-09-07  2021-09-06   Y    N  2021-09-06
70 17AB 2021-09-06 Y  N  2021-09-08  2021-09-06   Y    N  2021-09-06
70 17AB 2021-09-06 Y  N  2021-09-09  2021-09-06   Y    N  2021-09-06
70 17AB 2021-09-06 Y  N  2021-09-10  2021-09-06   Y    N  2021-09-06
70 17AX 2021-09-13 -  N  2021-09-13  2021-09-06   Y    N  2021-09-06
70 17AX 2021-09-13 -  N  2021-09-14  2021-09-06   Y    N  2021-09-06
70 17AX 2021-09-13 -  N  2021-09-15  2021-09-06   Y    N  2021-09-06
```

**If the goal is to find the values of ADD1 and ADD2 from the most recent DATE** in BETA then perhaps you really want to interleave the observations by date instead of merging.  Then even if the DATE in BETA is a week before the DATE in ALPHA the values of ADD1 and ADD2 will be copied onto the observations from ALPHA.

Make new variables to retain the values of ADD1 and ADD2 from the observations read from BETA onto the following observations for ALPHA.

```
data alpha; 
  input ID $ PKG $ IS $ SE $ DATE :yymmdd.;
  format date yymmdd10.;
cards;
70 17AB Y N 2021-09-07
70 17AB Y N 2021-09-08
70 17AB Y N 2021-09-09
70 17AB Y N 2021-09-10
70 17AX - N 2021-09-13
70 17AX - N 2021-09-14
70 17AX - N 2021-09-15
;

data beta;
  input ID $ PKG $ DATE :yymmdd. Add1 Add2 ;
  format DATE yymmdd10.;
cards;
70 17AB 2021-09-06 Y N
70 17AX 2021-09-06 Y N
;

data want;
  set beta(in=inb) alpha(in=ina);
  by id pkg date;
  if inb then do; 
    retain _add1 _add2;
    _add1=add1; 
    _add2=add2;
    rename _add1=add1 _add2=add2;
    drop add1 add2;
  end;
  if ina then output;
  if last.pkg then call missing(_add1,_add2);
run;
```

Results

```
ID    PKG           DATE    IS    SE    add1    add2

70    17AB    2021-09-07    Y     N       Y       N
70    17AB    2021-09-08    Y     N       Y       N
70    17AB    2021-09-09    Y     N       Y       N
70    17AB    2021-09-10    Y     N       Y       N
70    17AX    2021-09-13    -     N       Y       N
70    17AX    2021-09-14    -     N       Y       N
70    17AX    2021-09-15    -     N       Y       N
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I never knew about retain! I’ll have to keep this stored in the memory bank for future use

Answer (score 0):

So as Tom mentioned what I had does work. For some reason it was bugging out when I was running it yesterday. I think the issue was in my code I had my by variables in the wrong order when I typed them wrong on here. A silly mistake but none the less thank you Tom for the help!

```
DATA Alpha; drop monday;
Merge Alpha (in=a) Beta (in=b);
by id pkg week;
if a;
```

run;